# if immediate child is a paragraph, highlight. If it is an image, add border

Tags: jquery

I have the following code :

```
$(".highlight").hover(function(){
                $(this).css("background-color","#E3EBC2");
                },function(){
                $(this).css("background-color","transparent");
                });
```

I was wondering how I could highlight if the immediate child of this class was a paragraph, and add a border if it was an image

```
<div class = "highlight>
<p>
some text
</p>
</div>
```

so the immediate child would be the p (only one level down the tree)

Comment: "immediate child" means the first child?

Comment: added more clarity above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to combine a [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) with a [first child filter](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and then use an [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is) call to see what you get, something like this:

```
$('.highlight').hover(
    function() {
        var $child = $(this).find('> :first-child');
        if($child.is('p'))
            $child.css("background-color", "#E3EBC2");
        else if($child.is('img'))
            $child.css('border', '3px solid #E3EBC2');
    }, function() {
        var $child = $(this).find('> :first-child');
        if($child.is('p'))
            $child.css("background-color", "transparent");
        else if($child.is('img'))
            $child.css('border', 'none');
    }
);
```

And a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kSmXQ/

Or, if you want to play with some CSS:

```
.highlight.highlighted > p {
    background-color: #E3EBC2;
}
.highlight.highlighted > img {
    border: 3px solid #E3EBC2;
}
```

And the jQuery to go with that:

```
$('.highlight > p:first-child, .highlight > img:first-child').parent().hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('highlighted');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
    }
);
```

And a live version of this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LPga3/1/

Thanks to [Ghostoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395952/ghostoy) for the idea behind this one.

---

And if you want the background color or border change on the `<div>` rather than the `<p>` or `<img>` child:

```
$('.highlight').hover(
    function() {
        var $this  = $(this);
        var $child = $this.find('> :first-child');
        if($child.is('p'))
            $this.css("background-color", "#E3EBC2");
        else if($child.is('img'))
            $this.css('border', '3px solid #E3EBC2');
    }, function() {
        var $this  = $(this);
        var $child = $this.find('> :first-child');
        if($child.is('p'))
            $this.css("background-color", "transparent");
        else if($child.is('img'))
            $this.css('border', 'none');
    }
);
```

Live example of this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ufLaW/

Comment: @Ghostoy: Nice. Or this as a variant of my first one: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LPga3/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(.highlight:first-child p)

$(.highlight:first-child img)
```

Might work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want highlight the .highlight element(`<div>`) instead of the immediate child(`<p>` or `<img>`), you probably should use this code: http://jsfiddle.net/ghostoy/LPga3/.

CSS:

```
.hlbackground {
    background-color: #E3EBC2;
}

.hlborder {
    border: 3px solid #E3EBC2;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.highlight > p:first-child').parent().hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('hlbackground');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hlbackground');
    }
);

$('.highlight > img:first-child').parent().hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('hlborder');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hlborder');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".highlight").hover(function(){
    $('p', this).css("background-color","#E3EBC2");
},function(){
    $('img', this).css("border","solid");
});
```